# android SIGSEGV in mono_gc_collect

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, segmentation-fault

We've got a unity engine game in soft launch now. We're seeing an ocassional crash with the callstack below - a few a day with a DAU of over 150. The crash doesn't seem common to any particular android version or device. There are lots of samsungs affected, but that could just be demographics.

Since this is GC, I guess it could be out-of-memory. But the callstack mentions cleanup, not allocating. We're currently shipping only standard texture format, rather that multiple APKs; I have no idea if that's related.

Has anyone seen this before? Can you decypher the runes?

```
Error: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 6d299ff0 Build fingerprint: 'htc/v01_htc_telus/htc_v01_u:4.4.2/KOT49H/1.02.661.6:user/release-keys' Revision: '0' pid: 12019, tid: 12043, name: main >>> com.spryfox.alphabear <<< r0 6d299ff0 r1 6d29a000 r2 fffffe5c r3 6d29a000 r4 6d299ff0 r5 00000001 r6 6d299ffc r7 7340b774 r8 609e15e0 r9 61f60f60 sl 62061688 fp 6205e8fc ip 61216ed0 sp 6205e8d0 lr 6113201c pc 61131f8c cpsr 48393454
libmono.002c8f8c:-2
libmono.GC_push_all_stack in GC_push_all_stack:72
libmono.002d4618:-2
libmono.002d46e8:-2
libmono.002ce770:-2
libmono.002cad8c:-2
libmono.002c7364:-2
libmono.002bd2f4:-2
libmono.002bcd38:-2
libmono.002bdb9c:-2
libmono.002bdc3c:-2
libmono.mono_gc_collect in mono_gc_collect:40
libmono.mono_domain_finalize in mono_domain_finalize:96
libmono.00026ad8:-2
libmono.mono_jit_cleanup in mono_jit_cleanup:20
libunity.0020c16c:-2
libunity.002a2338:-2
libunity.003d1f2c:-2
libunity.003daad0:-2
libdvm.dvmPlatformInvoke in dvmPlatformInvoke:112
libdvm.dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*) in dvmCallJNIMethod:484
libdvm.00027c68:-2
libdvm.dvmMterpStd(Thread*) in dvmMterpStd:76
libdvm.dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*) in dvmInterpret:188
libdvm.dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list) in dvmCallMethodV:340
libdvm.dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...) in dvmCallMethod:20
libdvm.00057b01:-2
libc.__thread_entry in __thread_entry:72
```